# Wordpress metabox of template list in admin site is not display

Tags: wordpress

below is a screen shot.
metabox of template is not working.
I had used "kallyas" theme.
can anyone help me?

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name : Stack Widget
 */
    get_header(); ?>

<?php
// GET GLOBALS

global $content_and_sidebar;

$meta_fields = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'zn_meta_elements', true);
$meta_fields = maybe_unserialize( $meta_fields );


if ( post_password_required() ) {

    $meta_fields['content_main_area'] = '';
    $meta_fields['content_bottom_area'] = '';
    $meta_fields['content_grey_area'] = '';
}



/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ACTION BOX AREA
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


if ( isset ( $meta_fields['action_box_area'] ) && is_array ( $meta_fields['action_box_area'] ) ) {

    zn_get_template_from_area ('action_box_area',$post->ID,$meta_fields);
}



/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CONTENT AREA
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/



// Here will check if sidebar is enabled

$content_css = 'span12';
$has_sidebar = false;
$mainbody_css = '';


// WE CHECK IF THIS IS NOT A PAGE FROM OUR THEME    

if ( empty ( $meta_fields['page_layout'] ) || empty ( $meta_fields['sidebar_select'] ) ) {

    if ( $data['page_sidebar_position'] == 'left_sidebar' ) {

        $content_css = 'span9 zn_float_right zn_content';

        $has_sidebar = true;

        $mainbody_css = 'zn_has_sidebar';

    }

    elseif ( $data['page_sidebar_position'] == 'right_sidebar' ) {

        $content_css = 'span9 zn_content';

        $has_sidebar = true;

        $mainbody_css = 'zn_has_sidebar';

    }

}   

// WE CHECK IF WE HAVE LEFT SIDEBAR

elseif ( $meta_fields['page_layout'] == 'left_sidebar' || ( $meta_fields['page_layout'] == 'default' && !empty ( $data['page_sidebar_position'] ) && $data['page_sidebar_position'] == 'left_sidebar' )   )

{

    $content_css = 'span9 zn_float_right zn_content';

    $has_sidebar = true;

    $mainbody_css = 'zn_has_sidebar';

}

// WE CHECK IF WE HAVE RIGHT SIDEBAR

elseif ( $meta_fields['page_layout'] == 'right_sidebar' || ( $meta_fields['page_layout'] == 'default' && !empty ( $data['page_sidebar_position'] ) && $data['page_sidebar_position'] == 'right_sidebar' )  )

{

    $content_css = 'span9 zn_content';

    $has_sidebar = true;

    $mainbody_css = 'zn_has_sidebar';

}



echo '<section id="content">';



if ( $content_and_sidebar ) { 



    while (have_posts()) : the_post();



    ob_start();

    the_content();

    $content = ob_get_clean();



//  $content = get_the_content();

    //$content_check = apply_filters('the_content', get_the_content());

    if ( !empty($content) || ( isset ( $meta_fields['page_title_show'] ) && $meta_fields['page_title_show'] == 'yes' ) || ( isset ( $meta_fields['content_main_area'] ) && is_array ( $meta_fields['content_main_area'] ) && ( isset( $meta_fields['page_builder_layout'] ) && $meta_fields['page_builder_layout'] == 'style1' ) ) ) {



        $row_margin = 'zn_content_no_margin';

        $row_style = 'row';



        if ( $content || $has_sidebar ) {

            $row_margin = '';

        }



        if ( isset( $meta_fields['page_builder_layout'] ) && $meta_fields['page_builder_layout'] == 'style1' ) {

            $row_style = 'row-fluid zn_def_margin zn_has_sidebar';

        }



        echo '<div class="container">';



        echo '<div class="mainbody '.$mainbody_css.'">';



                echo '<div class="'.$row_style.' '.$row_margin.'">';



                    echo '<div class="'.$content_css.'">';



                        // TITLE CHECK

                        if ( isset ( $meta_fields['page_title_show'] ) && $meta_fields['page_title_show'] == 'yes' ) {

                            echo '<h1 class="page-title">'.get_the_title().'</h1>';

                        }



                        // PAGE CONTENT

                        echo $content;



                        if ( !empty($data['zn_enable_page_comments']) && $data['zn_enable_page_comments'] == 'yes'  ) {

                            if ( isset( $data['zn_set_location_page_comments'] ) && (int)$data['zn_set_location_page_comments'] == 0 ) {

                                ?>

                                <!-- DISQUS comments block -->

                                <div class="disqusForm">

                                    <?php comments_template(); ?>

                                </div>

                                <div class="clear"></div>

                                <!-- end DISQUS comments block -->

                            <?php

                            }

                        }



/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
START CONTENT AREA 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

if ( isset ( $meta_fields['content_main_area'] ) && is_array ( $meta_fields['content_main_area'] ) && ( isset( $meta_fields['page_builder_layout'] ) && $meta_fields['page_builder_layout'] == 'style1' ) ) {

                        zn_get_template_from_area ('content_main_area',$post->ID,$meta_fields,true);

                    }





                    echo '</div>';





                    // START SIDEBAR OPTIONS

                    // WE CHECK IF THIS IS NOT A PAGE FROM THE THEME

                    if ( empty ( $meta_fields['page_layout'] ) || empty ( $meta_fields['sidebar_select'] ) ) {

                        if ( $data['page_sidebar_position'] == 'left_sidebar' || $data['page_sidebar_position'] == 'right_sidebar' ) {

                            echo '<div class="span3">';

                                echo '<div id="sidebar" class="sidebar">';

                                    if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar($data['page_sidebar']) ) : endif;

                                echo '</div>';

                            echo '</div>';

                        }

                    }

                    // WE CHECK IF WE HAVE A SIDEBAR SET IN PAGE OPTIONS

                    elseif ( ( ( $meta_fields['page_layout'] == 'left_sidebar' || $meta_fields['page_layout'] == 'right_sidebar' ) && $meta_fields['sidebar_select'] != 'default' ) || (  $meta_fields['page_layout'] == 'default' && $data['page_sidebar_position'] != 'no_sidebar' && $meta_fields['sidebar_select'] != 'default' ) ) 

                    { 



                                echo '<div class="span3">';

                                    echo '<div id="sidebar" class="sidebar">';

                                        if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar( $meta_fields['sidebar_select'] ) ) : endif;

                                    echo '</div>';

                                echo '</div>';

                    }

                    // WE CHECK IF WE HAVE A SIDEBAR SET FROM THEME'S OPTIONS

                    elseif ( $meta_fields['page_layout'] == 'default' && $data['page_sidebar_position'] != 'no_sidebar' && $meta_fields['sidebar_select'] == 'default' || ( ( $meta_fields['page_layout'] == 'left_sidebar' || $meta_fields['page_layout'] == 'right_sidebar' ) && $meta_fields['sidebar_select'] == 'default' ) ) {

                        echo '<div class="span3">';

                            echo '<div id="sidebar" class="sidebar">';

                                if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar($data['page_sidebar']) ) : endif;

                            echo '</div>';

                        echo '</div>';

                    }





                echo '</div>';



            echo '</div>';



        echo '</div>';

        }

    endwhile;

}



/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
START CONTENT AREA 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

if ( isset ( $meta_fields['content_main_area'] ) && is_array ( $meta_fields['content_main_area'] ) && ( !isset( $meta_fields['page_builder_layout'] ) || $meta_fields['page_builder_layout'] == 'default' ) ) {

    echo '<div class="container">';

        zn_get_template_from_area ('content_main_area',$post->ID,$meta_fields);

    echo '</div>';

}



/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
START GRAY AREA
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/



$cls = '';

if ( !isset ( $meta_fields['content_bottom_area'] ) || !is_array ( $meta_fields['content_bottom_area'] ) ) {

    $cls = 'noMargin';

}



if ( isset ( $meta_fields['content_grey_area'] ) && is_array ( $meta_fields['content_grey_area'] ) ) {

echo '<div class="gray-area '.$cls.'">';

    echo '<div class="container">';



        zn_get_template_from_area ('content_grey_area',$post->ID,$meta_fields);



    echo '</div>';

echo '</div>';

}









/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
START BOTTOM AREA
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/





if ( isset ( $meta_fields['content_bottom_area'] ) && is_array ( $meta_fields['content_bottom_area'] ) ) {

    echo '<div class="container">';

        zn_get_template_from_area ('content_bottom_area',$post->ID,$meta_fields);

    echo '</div>';

}


echo '</section><!-- end #content -->';


?>



<div class="container">

<?php

    if ( !empty($data['zn_enable_page_comments']) && $data['zn_enable_page_comments'] == 'yes'  ) {

        if ( isset( $data['zn_set_location_page_comments'] ) && (int)$data['zn_set_location_page_comments'] == 1 ) {

            ?>

            <!-- DISQUS comments block -->

            <div class="disqusForm">

        <?php comments_template(); ?>

        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>

        <!-- end DISQUS comments block -->

    <?php

        }

    }

?>

</div>





<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: can you ellaborate more, and provide only specific part of codes instead of whole file?

Comment: I mean to say 
even I added " Template Name : Stack Widget " it will not display in admin site.
metabox of template is not at there in admin site.

Comment: Try this and see if it can solve your issue: bit.ly/tmplt-box

Answer (score 0):

It will display in admin page

```
<?php
/*
* Template Name: Stack Widget
*/
get_header(); ?>
```

Comment: you did not get me...I mean in wordpress admin panel when I add new page then I can not show template list.